# From where can i download C language libraries?

Tags: c, linux

I have a problem that when i compile a program whit `pow` or `cos` it be like: 
`main':<br/>just-test.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference tosqrt'
just-test.c:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to 'pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
p.s: "im using linux and atom editor"

Comment: Please show your compilation statement.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to download anything. But you have to tell the linker, that it should add the math library to your executable. Do this by adding `-lm` to the linker command line.

`-l` adds a ***l***ibrary to linking, and the math library is simply called `m`.

Comment: Ideally true, but you never know. :)

Comment: where do i add it ?

Comment: @MahDjaay: To the linker flags. Atom is really just an editor and not a fully blown IDE. So it really comes to the build system you're using. Are you using Makefiles, or CMake or SCons, or… ;there are hundreds of build systems, each with its own way do to this. However in the end, you just want to add that `-lm` to the linker command line. Like this. First compile `cc -c foobar.c` (generated `foobar.o`) then link (`cc -o foobar -lm foobar.o`). Rather sooner than later you have to learn about the steps that go into building the actual program binary, and not rely on some "IDE magic".